# are there different levels of administrator accounts?

Tags: administrator

I need to set up a secondary administrator without the right to change the primary administrator password.  I want the secondary administrator to have the ability to add new programs to the computer, but do not want him to be able to change the primary administrator account password.

Comment: You can start by specifying the OS.

Answer (score 0):

The can only be three account types. The administrator (root) the limited, and the guest.